# Storing Blog posts in Amazon s3 storage vs Mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3

I am planning to create a SASS like blogger.com , In future there may be million and millions of posts.What is the best way to store this.

Example of my Mysql columns

```
Title , Date , author , Content
```

Now should i store the blog contents in mysql itself as text field or I can store the posts as text in s3 and reference the path of the s3 in content column , so it saves space in mysql and keep the table fast.

P.s : I don't want search features in content column ,.

Where do blogger.com or anyother companies with lots of Text store their data.

If you guys have any Ideal way to store this data for fastest retrieval , please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Images, yes.  Text, no.

I assume your web server will build a page with various things including the "content" (text) and possibly images.  Since the structure of HTML / HTTP is to build all the text and then pull in the images after laying out the text, it is better to get all the text at once.  The images, on the other hand, can be handled separately with `<img...>` or `<picture...>`.

"Fastest retrieval" -- Assuming the text is stored with its metadata, it is "fastest" to retrieve both in a single SQL `SELECT`.

But, as I mentioned above, "images" are different.  You should get the URLs for the images at the time you get the rest of the content, but let the user's browser "pull" the images asynchronously *after* the content is handled.